Can I modify the "Try It" behavior in Azure Developer Portal so that the optional parameters don't appear to be required?
Our APIs have some optional request parameters, and the way the "Try It" feature in Developer Portal handles these optional parameters is problematic for us, because there is no obvious indicator that the parameter is optional (the trashcan isn't enough to clue in our API-consumer customers), and it shows up with the drop-down menu selection on the first item in the list of possible values. It's not obvious to the user that you can just click the trashcan to get rid of it.
Is there a workaround to improve this? Our Developer Portal is not self-hosted, so we can't override the behavior with JavaScript. We would like to add a more obvious indicator of what is required, such as a red asterisk on the required parameters.
Illustration of what our request body spec looks like:


{
"required": [
    "myRequiredParam"
],
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "myRequiredParam": {
        "type": "array",
        ...
    },

    "myOptionalParam": {
        "enum": [
            "F",
            "M"
        ],
        "type": "string",
        "description": "An optional param you can leave out of your request"
    }
}



Example of what an optional parameter looks like in the "Try It" UI:


Both Mandatory and optional parameters looks differently in developer portal. Optional parameter comes with delete option where are mandatory parameter doesn't have such option nor you can change the parameter itself like optional one here.

That is a good point. The problem is that our customers who are using our API don't realize that the trashcan icon indicates that the param is optional. It's not obvious enough, to the point where they wind up implementing endpoints with optional params they don't want. The best option might be to add a red asterix on  the required fields, since that's the conventional way of indicating that something is 'required'. Thank you for pointing that out. I will update my question.
